# How can i disable my input and the content inside using a selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have looked around and haven't found a solution to my problem, I am trying to learn javascript and jquery. what I want to learn is how can I do so when I select the `option` "none" the `<input>` and the data inside it, should be disabled.

this is my attempts:

First attempt link:http://jsfiddle.net/kmtLy705/7/

First attempt code: (Works with buttons)

```
<input disabled id="page_navigation1" type="number">

<button class="add">Add</button>
<button class="remove">Remove</button>

<select>
  <option value="0" class="add" selected>None</option>
  <option value="1" class="remove">select</option>
  <option value="2" class="remove">select</option>
  <option value="3" class="remove">select</option>
  <option value="4" class="remove">select</option>
  <option value="5" class="remove">select</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('#page_navigation1').attr('disabled', true)
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
  $('#page_navigation1').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

Now, this code works with buttons but I have tried countless ways to make it work with an option and haven't found a solution yet.

Second attempt link: http://jsfiddle.net/5u9pfot0/1/ this doesn't work at all but the idea was there (when val1 is selected then the input should be disabled)

Second attempt code:

```
<select id="selectid" name="selectname">
  <option value="val1" id="valid1"> Val1 </option>
  <option value="val2" id="valid2"> Val2 </option>
  <option value="val3" id="valid3"> Val3 </option>
</select>

<input disabled id="page_navigation1" type="number">
```

jquery:

```
  if (document.getElementById('selectid').value == "val1") {
  $('#page_navigation1').attr('disabled', true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your second approach just a little.
Try doing below:

```js
function callthis()
{
if (document.getElementById('selectid').value == "val1") {
  $('#page_navigation1').attr('disabled', true);
} 
else
 $('#page_navigation1').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectid" name="selectname" onchange="callthis();">
    <option default disabled>Choose one</option>
    <option value="val1" id="valid1"> Val1 </option>
    <option value="val2" id="valid2"> Val2 </option>
    <option value="val3" id="valid3"> Val3 </option>
</select>

<input disabled id="page_navigation1" type="number">
```

Comment: That works really well Thanks alot! :) will mark as answered when i can

Comment: @Ladia smell like you have another account

Comment: @DreamHunter-hashADH How so? this is my first :)